# fitbound function with the direction of progress

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Please understand that we communicate using a translator due to our lack of English skills.

We are currently developing a map using React and Mapbox.

We used the coding below because we wanted to set the initial location of the map when the page was loaded.

[coding]

```
    const bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds();


     cgoData?.forEach((cgoItem: any) => {


       bounds.extend([cgoItem?.prtLogt, cgoItem?.prtLat]);


     });

     mapRef.current?.fitBounds(bounds, {

      duration: 1000,

});
```

However, the 'fitBounds' function sets the center point of the nearest distance as the initial position.

We want to set the initial position, including the direction of the ship's progress, which is not always the shortest distance.

[The screen you see now]

[image]

[The screen that we want]

[image]

How can I set it up?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the question, but if I did, there are a few things:

1. Get to know turf, a set of utils that will help you. For example, it's [bbox function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/bbox) will compute a bounding box from an array or a FeatureCollection (geojson).
2. Now, if you want to leave some padding, you can specify it in the [fitBounds method](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#fitbounds). Specifically, look into `options.padding`